# delete after new [] : with or without user destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, heap-corruption

Deleting a pointer to an array allocated with `new []` is "undefined behaviour". I'm just curious why the first `delete` in the following code leads to heap corruption IF the destructor is defined, otherwise nothing happens (as I humbly expected). Tested with Visual Studio 8 and GNU GCC version 4.7.2 (http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php).

```
struct A
{
   //~A() {}
};

int main()
{
   A* a = new A[10];
   delete a;    //  heap corruption when the user destructor is defined

   int *b = new int[100];
   delete b;    //  no heap corruption
};
```

Comment: Because undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is, by it's core, undefined and can mean that anything could happen.

Comment: @Joachim: While true, there is a reason for everything that happens in a machine, even if it's out of the scope of the language. UB doesn't magically turn off the laws of physics.

Comment: I'm interested in the reason: both compilers do the same.

Comment: To find the reason a specific compiler behaves the way it does, you might have to look at the generated assembler code. If that doesn't help then you have to use a debugger to actually step into all library function calls to see what's really happening.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I'll try it, but it seems such an easy sample.

Comment: That's the problem with undefined behavior. The behavior can even change between minor updates to either a compiler or the runtime library. To learn why some undefined behavior seemingly work on one compiler and not another, or why two compilers seems to behave the same (good or bad) you really have to go deep into the code of that specific compiler/library combination.

Comment: @lightnessracinginorbit obviously you have not seen the undefined bahaviour I have.

Comment: And please forgive my very humble curiosity! I like the people getting points answering nonsense below. Next time I'll try `Dangeons & Dragons` or `Games of thrones` sections.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Correct; my interpretation of this question is that that is what the OP is asking for. Indeed, the answer here is largely "we don't have enough details to do such a 'deep dive', and usually we don't bother anyway".

Comment: @Yakk: One does not simply... _see_ undefined behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UB is not something you can rationalise about within the scope of the language, and at least without detailed knowledge of the toolchain, optimisation level, operating system, architecture and processor.

At a guess, though: with no destructor to call, the compiler is simply not generating any code that makes your code's fault visible in the real world. Such a destructor call may be hitting the header of your dynamically allocated memory block, which doesn't exist in the single `new A` example.

Comment: That's true, adding a `std::string` member forces the compiler to generate a destructor and the heap corruption reappears.

Comment: Sorry, -1 for "UB is not something you can rationalise about". Neither true nor helpful to the question. Rather, I agreed with your comment on the question where you said that anything a deterministic machine does can be rationalised about. All UB means is that you can't use the C++ standard alone to rationalize about it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Better now?

Answer (score 5):

Mismatching `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]` is *undefined behaviour*. Really, that's the end of the discussion.

Anything can happen after that. It's rather pointless to analyse further.

Answer (score 3):

It is overwhelmingly likely that the reason is that when you `new[]` an array of a type which is not trivially destructible, the implementations stores the size of the array at the start of the block it gets from the underlying allocation mechanism. It needs this so that it knows how many objects to destroy when you `delete[]`

When it returns the address of the first element of the array, this will differ from the address of the block it allocated by some number of bytes, probably `sizeof(size_t)`.

As a memory-saving optimization, for types that don't need destruction it doesn't do this.

So, `delete[]` will do a different thing according to whether or not the type has a destructor. If it does then it will look at the bytes preceding the pointer it is given, destroy that many objects, subtract the offset and free the block. If it doesn't then it will just free the address it is given. As it happens, "just free the address" is also what `delete` does in the case of a type with no destructor, and so when you mismatch them you "get away with" the UB on this implementation.

Now, there may be other mechanisms that will produce the same results you're seeing, and you could in principle check the source of this specific version of GCC to confirm. But I'm pretty sure I remember that this is how GCC used to do it, so it probably still does.

Answer (score 2):

From a language point of view the only thing that matters is that it is Undefined Behavior. Anything goes. But that does not mean that you cannot explain the behavior you are getting.

The first thing to note is that the key difference is not that you provided a user destructor, but that the *destructor* (implicitly defined or user defined) is not *trivial*. Basically a destructor is trivial if it does nothing at all (the compiler cannot consider a user provided destructor as trivial). The cases where you might not have a user provided destructor and the destructor may still be non-trivial include any case in which a subobject (member or base) has a non-trivial destructor.

```
struct NonTrivialDestructor {
   std::string s;
};
struct NotTrivialEither : NonTrivialDestructor {};
```

Now with that being said, the main difference in the two cases where you are experiencing the crash and not is that in the latter case the compiler *knows* that destructors won't do anything and it thus knows that it won't make a difference if they are called or not.

The importance of this statement is that in the case where destructors *do* (or *may do*) something, the compiler must ensure that the generated code calls as many destructors as needed. Since the pointer returned by `new[]` does not hold the information of how many objects were allocated (and thus need being destroyed) that information needs to be tracked somewhere else. The most common approach is that the compiler will generate code that allocates one additional `size_t` object, it will set the value to be the number of objects and allocate the rest of the array, construct all objects, etc. The layout of memory would be:

```
 v
 +------+---+---+---+--
 | size | T | T | T |...
 +------+---+---+---+--
        ^
```

The pointer returned by `new[]` needs to hold the address of the first object which means that even though the underlying allocator (`operator new`) returns the pointer `v`, `new[]` will return `^` in the above drawing.

The additional information allows `delete[]` to know how many constructors to call, basically doing something like:

```
pseudo-delete[](T * p) {
   size_t *size = reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(p)-1;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < *size; ++i) 
      (p+i)->~T();
   deallocate(size);
}
```

That is, `delete[]` extracts the information from the previous memory location, uses that to drive how many destructors to run and then releases the memory that was allocated from the system (pointer `v` in the drawing).

On the other hand, `delete` is meant to handle deletion of a single object, for that there is no additional counts needed (the count must be 1), so there is no additional information tracked. The pseudo code for plain `delete` would just call `p->~T()` and `deallocate(p)` directly. This is where you get the crash.

The memory allocated by the underlying mechanism was at address `v`, but you attempted to release `^`, causing the library to fail and crash.

In the case of `new[]` with types that have trivial destructors, the compiler knows that calling the destructor will not do anything, so it skips the operation completely, which in the pseudo code above means that the `for` loop is gone. This in turn removes the need for the additional `size_t`, and the memory returned by a call to `new []` has the following layout:

```
 v
 +---+---+---+--
 | T | T | T |...
 +---+---+---+--
 ^
```

In this case the pointer obtained from the memory allocator and the pointer returned by `new[]` are in the same location, which means that when `delete` is evaluated the pointer used to deallocate is the same that was used to allocate.

It is important to note that all this discussion is about implementation details, this is **undefined behavior** in the standard and some implementation might opt to always track the size, or use a different mechanism to track the number of elements and everything here discussed would be bogus. You **cannot** depend on this behavior, but I hope that it will help people understand why the standard requires matching `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]`.